# An (admittedly simplistic) argument for the truth of the Goldbach conjecture?

Tags: number-theory

Trivially, each odd natural number $n, n \ge 7$ can be written as the sum of 2, a prime number and an even number: $n = 2 + p + e$, with e an even number. Now let 
 $n_1 = 2 + p_1 +e _1$
$n_2 = 2 + p_2 + e_2$
Then $n_1 + n_2 = 4 + p_1 + p_2 + e_3$, with $e_3 = e_1 + e_2$. 
Hence $n_1 + n_2 - 4 - e_3 = p_1 + p_2$. 
Now the above's lhs ranges through the even numbers greater than or equal to $6$ (let $n_1 = n_2 = 7$, with $7 = 2 + 3 + 2$, which yields $6 = 3 + 3$).
Doesn't this, by induction upon the infinite number of primes, argue for the truth of the (strong) Goldbach conjecture ?

Comment: You have not proven that every even number is of the form $n_1 + n_2 - 4 - e_1 - e_2$.

Comment: How do you know that it ranges through all even numbers greater than or equal to 6?  You gave one example to show that you can get 6, but what about all the other even numbers?

Comment: @user1379857 I do think so. Every odd number $n$, $n ≥ 7$, can be written as the sum of a prime $p$, $p < n$, and an even number $m$. I simply break up $m$ into $2 + e$. If this is true, then every even number ≥ 6 is of the form $n_1 + n_2 - 4 - e_1 - e_2$, with $n_1$, $n_2$ odd.

Comment: You haven't given any properties the primes $p$ must take.  For the purposes of proving any odd $n$ can be written as $n = 2 + p + e$ for any $n$ you could just set $p = 3$ and $e = n - 5$.  But if you put $p_i = 3$ throughout you've only proven that $6 = 3+3$ is the sum of two primes.

Comment: might want to restrict your evens. otherwise (p2+4)+(p1) is a possible Goldbach partition into two primes of n1+n2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now the above's lhs ranges through the even numbers greater than or equal to $6$ (let $n_1 = n_2 = 7$, with $7 = 2 + 3 + 2$, which yields $6 = 3 + 3$).

It ranges through at least *some* of the even numbers greater than or equal to $6$, but how do you know it ranges through *all* of them? That's the tricky part.

> Doesn't this, by induction upon the infinite number of primes, argue for the truth of the (strong) Goldbach conjecture ?

Well, it shows that out of all of the even numbers greater than or equal to $4$, *infinitely many* of them are the sum of two prime numbers. But that doesn't mean that *all* of them can.

By the way, here's a potential way to highlight the problem with your argument.

Define a "trime number" as a prime number whose decimal expansion ends in a 3. Now look at your argument again, replacing "prime number" with "trime number" everywhere. The conclusion is false (which is that every even number greater than or equal to $6$ is the sum of two trime numbers), so you should be able to find a flaw in this new argument.

But once you've found the flaw in the new argument, you've found the flaw in the original argument, because your argument doesn't make use of any property which distinguishes prime numbers from trime numbers.

Comment: We know the lhs ranges through *all* of the even number by starting out at $n_1 =7$, $n_2 = 7$ and then first increasing $n_1$ with $2$, then increasing $n_2$ with $2$, wash, rinse, repeat. The part about the (trivial) representation of each of the $n_i$ as $n_i = 2 + p_i + e_i$ remains true.

Comment: @vikingpower: But when you change the $n_i$, the $e_i$ also change.

Comment: What are the rules/how do you prove that $n$ exists once you hit $13=2+9+2$? You can find new primes/n by hand, but how do you generalize?

Comment: @EricWofsey Not necessarily. For example, if $p_i$ is the smallest of two twin primes.

Comment: @KitterCatter 9 is not a prime. The rule is that the $p_i$ are primes. We are certain that there are at least $ \lfloor \frac{n}{ln n} \rfloor$ primes to play with as $n$ increases.

Comment: @vikingpower. There are a lot of primes to play with isn't a good proof though. That is precisely the point

Comment: I do like the meta-argument in the update @Tanner Swett